# How to give focus to children when date picker is opened Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, datepicker, accessibility, keyboard-navigation

I have a date picker control which is used to select date. In Accessibility Mode, i.e when I use Keyboard for selecting date date picker doesn't show focus border to indicate focused element for selection. And also there is tab loss. In order to give focus border or to avoid tab loss I need to access child elements of date picker.
Help needed for accessing child elements inside date picker which is created using date picker fragment in Xamarin android.
Else can anyone suggest me a date picker which supports accessibility features.

Comment: As far as I understand your question what you are trying to ask is that how will you gain access to date, month and year as a child in calendar for other functionalities right ?

Comment: Not exactly, I have to get child elements of a date picker (i.e TextView's EditText's inside the control)so that i can give a focus border to it when it's focused.

Comment: For that you need to dig the java calendar class on this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html and also this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html